# Mail Delivery system sending multiple mails with error " Undeliverable : Case is Rejected

Tags: case, administration, email2case

I have configured Email-to-Case in my org.We have also set up case auto-response rule. Whenver an email is sent, using email-to-case, a case is created and an auto response will be sent.This is working fine. But, For a case, auto-response mail was undelivered. Now, the mail delivery system keeps on reporting "Undeliverable: Case 5000a00000***** is Rejected" every 24 hours and all these mails are getting attached to case. These are coming in huge numbers and we are not understanding how to stop it.

1. Email is sent to Email-to-Case routing adress and case is created.
2. An auto-response mail was sent from Org wide Email.
3. Mail delivery system sent mail to org wide email after 24 hours :
   "A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
   recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:
   xyz@email.com (Undelivered): 554 5.4.7 [internal] exceeded max time without delivery"
4. Mail delivery system agian sent message to org wide emailafter 24hours : "Undeliverable: Case 5000a00000***** is Rejected". And this is occuring in loop now.

Why is it behaving in this way? Org wide email is routing the email -to -case mails to org. Is that the reason, all these emails are attached to case? How can we stop this?
Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: @sfdcfox Any help, it is an critical issue in my production day by day.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce does not provide any standard loop protection for such situation, To implement this you can use Apps from AppExchange like E2CP or you can customize case creation and mail handling by "Email Service" which will provide you better control for situation like undeliverable or Out of Office emails and avoid unnecessary data in Salesforce